# Special characters :$@ and--) and *) in bash's getopt

Tags: bash, getopt

```
vim  mytest.sh
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 ARGS=`getopt -o ab: -l "argv3:,help" -- "$@"`
  4 eval set -- "${ARGS}"
  5 
  6 while true;
  7 do
  8     case "$1" in
  9         -a)
 10             echo "i am a"
 11             shift
 12             ;;
 13         -b)
 14             echo "i am b, my value is $2"
 15             shift 2
 16             ;;
 17         --argv3)
 18             echo "i am argv3, my value is $2"
 19             shift 2
 20             ;;
 21         --help)
 22             echo "i am help info"
 23             exit 0
 24             ;;
 25         --)
 26             shift
 27             break
 28             ;;
 29         *)
 30             echo "Internal error!"
 31             exit 1
 32             ;;
 33     esac
 34 done
```

1. `"$@"` expands into a list of separate parameters. What does `-- "$@"` mean in getopt? If I change the 3rd line into

   ```
   ARGS=`getopt -o ab: -l "argv3:,help"`
   ```

which function will disappear for `test.sh?`

2. `--)` in the 25th line

   ```
    25         --)
    26             shift
    27             break
    28             ;;
   ```

   Which meaning does the coder want to express?
3. `*)` in the 29th line

   On which condition or what argument will evoke the output of "Internal error!"  in terminal?

Comment: *" What does `-- "$@"` mean in getopt?"* -- it does not have any special meaning. `--` is a special argument that tells many programs to stop searching for options in their command line and interpret the remaining arguments as files (or something else, depending on program). You already know what `"$@"` means.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just purely matches a parameter containing two minus sign, `--`.

Edit: as @axiac mentioned, [this parameter usually has a special meaning, it signify the end of command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376).

2. Matches the parameter above.
3. [Wild card](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF), can be regarded as `default` in `switch-case`, which will be triggered while no cases match in the previous.

Comment: Why './mytest.sh  -d` can't trigger  "Internal error!".